# Creating 2d array from arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a constant 2d int array which is declared as:

```
int blocked[][] = new int[][] { { 0, 4 }, { 2, 2 }, { 3, 1 }, { 3, 3 } };
```

However, what I would like to do is to generate the exact array dynamically. So I created an arraylist where I add each integer separately, 0,4,2,3...N. Then I use for loop to go through to arraylist and create a 2d array. But somehow I just can't get it to work. I can't figure out where I'm doing wrong.

```
        ArrayList<Integer> blocklist = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    int blocked[][];

    blocklist.add(0);
    blocklist.add(4);
    blocklist.add(2);
    blocklist.add(2);
    blocklist.add(3);
    blocklist.add(1);
    blocklist.add(3);
    blocklist.add(3);

    blocked = new int[blocklist.size()][2];


    for(int i=0; i+2 < blocklist.size(); i++){
        blocked[i][0] = blocklist.get(i);
        blocked[i][1] = blocklist.get(i+1);
    }


    for(int i=0;i<blocked.length;++i){
        System.out.print(blocked[i][0]);
    }
```

When I do Arrays.deepToString(blocked); 
I get `[[0, 0], [4, 4], [2, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3], [1, 1], [3, 3], [3, 3]]` but it should be `[[0, 4], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3]]`

Comment: for(int i=0; i< blocklist.size(); i+=2){
//body
}

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work. outputs 00203030

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Integer> blocklist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int blocked[][];

        blocklist.add(0);
        blocklist.add(4);
        blocklist.add(2);
        blocklist.add(2);
        blocklist.add(3);
        blocklist.add(1);
        blocklist.add(3);
        blocklist.add(3);



        blocked = new int[(blocklist.size()/2)][2];

        for (int i = -1, j = 0,k=0; k < blocklist.size(); j++) {
            blocked[j][0] = blocklist.get(++i);
            blocked[j][1] = blocklist.get(++i);
            k+=2;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <(blocklist.size()/2);i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                System.out.print(blocked[i][j]);
            }
        }

    System.out.println();
    String deepToString = Arrays.deepToString(blocked);
    System.out.println("string: "+deepToString);

output: 
04223133
string: [[0, 4], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. When I do Arrays.deepToString(blocked); I get [[0, 0], [4, 4], [2, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3], [1, 1], [3, 3], [3, 3]] but it should be [[0, 4], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3]]

Comment: Yep, that works perfectly. Thank you very much I see what I have done wrong now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int j = 0

for (int i=0; i < blocklist.size(); i++) {
    blocked[i][0] = blocklist.get(j);
    blocked[i][1] = blocklist.get(j+1);

    j+=2;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. When I do Arrays.deepToString(blocked); I get [[0, 0], [4, 4], [2, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3], [1, 1], [3, 3], [3, 3]] but it should be [[0, 4], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3]]

Comment: This should definitely work, glad to see you resolved your problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the for loop. i+2 increments i by 2 on each iteration of the loop.

It should be:

```
for(int i=0; i < blocklist.size(); i++){
    blocked[i][0] = blocklist.get(i);
    blocked[i][1] = blocklist.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. When I do Arrays.deepToString(blocked); I get [[0, 0], [4, 4], [2, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3], [1, 1], [3, 3], [3, 3]] but it should be [[0, 4], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3]]

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
    blocked = new int[blocklist.size()][2];

for(int i=0; i < blocklist.size(); i++){
blocked[i][0] = blocklist.get(i);
blocked[i][1] = blocklist.get(i);
```

}

```
for(int i=0;i<blocked.length;++i){
    System.out.print(blocked[i][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code changes `int[][]` to `ArrayList<>Integer>` and vice versa irrespective of length, the code is also available on [github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/JavaCoding_tutorials/blob/master/src/stack/overflow/test/first/TestDriveInteger.java)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * Created by Pankaj Nimgade on 10-02-2016.
 */
public class TestDriveInteger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int blocked[][] = new int[][]{{0, 4}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}};
        ArrayList<Integer> list = toArrayList(blocked);

        System.out.println("########### Converted integer List ##############");

        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.print(integer + " ");
        }

        int[][] source = toIntegerArray(list);

        System.out.println("########### Converted int array ##############");
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < source[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(source[i][j]+" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(source.length);
    }

    private static int[][] toIntegerArray(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList) {
        int[][] block = new int[arrayList.size() / 2][2];
        System.out.println(block.length);
        if ((arrayList.size() % 2) == 0) {

           int count = arrayList.size()/2;

            Iterator<Integer> integerIterator = arrayList.iterator();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                block[i][0] = integerIterator.next();
                block[i][1] = integerIterator.next();
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("it is not a even size");
        }

        return block;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Integer> toArrayList(int[][] integerArray) {
        ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < integerArray[i].length; j++) {
                integerArrayList.add(integerArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return integerArrayList;
    }
}
```

> output

```
########### Converted integer List ##############
0 4 2 2 3 1 3 3 4
########### Converted int array ##############
0 4 2 2 3 1 3 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Simple {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> blocklist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    blocklist.add(0);
    blocklist.add(4);
    blocklist.add(2);
    blocklist.add(2);
    blocklist.add(3);
    blocklist.add(1);
    blocklist.add(3);
    blocklist.add(3);

    int length = blocklist.size() / 2;

    int blocked[][];
    blocked = new int[ length ][2];

    for(int i=0, j=0; i < length; i++) {
        blocked[i][0] = blocklist.get(j++);
        blocked[i][1] = blocklist.get(j++);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        System.out.print(blocked[i][0] + " " + blocked[i][1] + "\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: after that you will get: [0 4] [2 2] [3 1] [3 3]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   for(int i=0,j=0; j < (blocklist.size()/2); i+=2,j++){
        blocked[j][0] = blocklist.get(i);
        blocked[j][1] = blocklist.get(i+1);
   }
   for(int i=0;i<blocked.length/2;++i){
        System.out.print(blocked[i][0]);
        System.out.print(blocked[i][1]);
   }
```

Working for me :)